# trouble with two locations in nginx config

Tags: nginx

I have 2 links: `myserver.org` and `myserver.org/support`
I need first link follow to `/var/www/myserver.org` and second to `/var/www/support`
My config now:
first file & link

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name groupmanager.org;
    charset utf-8;

    root /var/www/groupmanager.org;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/groupmanager.org_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/groupmanager.org_error.log;

    include /etc/nginx/templates/php-fpm.conf;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name www.groupmanager.org;
  rewrite ^(.*) http://groupmanager.org$1 permanent;
}
```

Second file & link:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name 163.172.88.31/support;
  charset utf-8;

  root /var/www/support;
  index index.php;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/support_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/support_error.log;

  include /etc/nginx/templates/php-fpm.conf;
}

server {

  listen 80;

  server_name www.163.172.88.31/support;
  rewrite ^(.*) http://163.172.88.31/support$1 permanent;
}
```

php-fpm.conf

```
location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files $uri =404;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
   deny all;
}

location ~* \.(gif|jpeg|jpg|txt|png|tif|tiff|ico|jng|bmp|doc|pdf|rtf|xls|ppt|rar|rpm|swf|zip|bin|exe|dll|deb|cur)$ {
  expires 168h;
}

location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
  expires 180m;
}
```

First link works fine, second - no. I see '403 Forbidden'
What is not rigth?
Permissions for folders are the same, I think, they are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

groupmanager.org.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name groupmanager.org;
    charset utf-8;

    root /var/www/groupmanager.org;
    index index.php;

    location /support/ {
        alias /var/www/support/;
        index index.php;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/support_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/support_error.log;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/groupmanager.org_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/groupmanager.org_error.log;

    include /etc/nginx/templates/php-fpm.conf;
}


server {
  listen 80;

  server_name www.groupmanager.org;
  rewrite ^(.*) http://groupmanager.org$1 permanent;
}
```

php-fpm.conf

```
location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files $uri =404;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
   deny all;
}

location ~* \.(gif|jpeg|jpg|txt|png|tif|tiff|ico|jng|bmp|doc|pdf|rtf|xls|ppt|rar|rpm|swf|zip|bin|exe|dll|deb|cur)$ {
  expires 168h;
}

location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
  expires 180m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For both /var/www/myserver.org and /var/www/support you have to make two separate nginx config file with two different roots and server names .

besides , if you just want to show two links you can setup nginx for one and link the second one with just an internal link ( if they are in the same page)

Comment: Now I use ip to access. Two files not works. All requests follow in first file.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    server {

        listen 80 default_server;

        server_name myserver.org;
        charset utf-8;

        root /var/www/myserver.org;
        index index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
```

in `/etc/nginx/default.d/` directory , create  a .config file  *test.config*:

```
location myserver.org {
proxy_pass /myserver.org;
}
location myserver.org/support {
proxy_pass /var/www/support;
}
```

Comment: What changes when I write it two times? I see the same error.

Comment: can u share the error and all ur nginx.config file ?

Comment: Error:Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
 nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/default.d/test.conf:1